# Rails / Puma (systemctl) / Fog worker issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, systemd, puma, fog-aws

I am running ruby "3.1.1", rails (7.0.3.1), fog-aws (3.14.0), fog-core (2.3.0) and I start puma using systemd. Requests come in through AWS ALB 443 -> 80.

Since implementing the fog-aws Gem my puma_access.log just keeps writing:
[31723] ! Unable to start worker
[31723] /var/www/iot/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/cache.rb:94:in `expand_path'
[31723] Early termination of worker

and any requests just 504 Gateway time-out. Running puma outside of systemctl seems to work ok.

/var/www/iot/shared/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/cache.rb:94 is:

`SANDBOX = ENV["HOME"] ? File.expand_path("~/.fog-cache") : File.expand_path(".fog-cache")`

Although I am not sure why that is relevant,  ENV["HOME"] = "/home/ec2-user"

Please help!

Comment: Server:
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

Comment: how is this not about programming? This is a Ruby on Rails app having issues with puma.

Comment: Do not place answers to your question here in the comment section. Create an answer and mark it as the solution.

Comment: Apologies @Rob have altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by setting env["HOME"] in my systemd process, but unsure why this helped.